# Can't change open-files-limit for mysql on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04 with MariaDB.  Mysql is a huge bottleneck for my server.  I have tried everything of which I am aware to raise the open files limit for mysql.  I have added `open-files-limit = 2097152` to my.cnf.  I have added the following to limits.conf:

```
* soft nofile 2097152
* hard nofile 2097152
* soft nproc 2097152
* hard nproc 2097152
mysql soft nofile 2097152
mysql hard nofile 2097152
mysql soft nproc 2097152
mysql hard nproc 2097152
```

I have added `session required pam_limits.so` to /etc/pam.d/common-session* and /etc/pam.d/sudo and a couple of others.  I have tried restarting mysql after reboot - no change.  I also checked `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` to see if it was involved but the file is empty.  After all that I still get the following:

```
# ulimit -Sa
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256538
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2097152
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

When I run `# mysqld --verbose` I get this:

`150501  0:19:35 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024`

Does anyone have any idea as to what is blocking this change???

Comment: If you systems uses systemd, try this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152186/mysql-max-open-files-more-than-1024#answer-157910

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no straight answer here. The stuff in /etc/security/limits.conf is read only by PAM stuff, during login, not during boot.

So, if you want mysqld to have it's ulimits altered you'll have to twiddle with the init script.